# How to capture c-lightining logs?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

Where does c-lightning save its debug.log file? I know you can run the lightning daemon with `--log-level=debug` and access the logs in the terminal. But, I run my node on a remote server and I access it via SSH and sometimes when my internet connection goes off for a second on the machine which I am accessing through, my SSH client times out. I was wondering if there is a location where c-lightning saves all these logs just like how Bitcoin-core saves its debug.log file in `~/.bitcoin` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C-lightning does not save logs by default. One can ensure that the logs are saved to the drive by including `log-file=<file_name>.log` in the config file. When staring `lightningd` you can include the level of logs that the file has to capture by including `--log-level=LEVEL`, where LEVEL can be `io`, `debug`, `info`, `unusual`, or `broken`.

Comment: As all command line arguments to lightningd these can also be stored as key value pairs in a config file which is either called `config` and stored in your lightning dir (by default at `~/.lightning`) or is passed as an argument to lightningd